# Merge aspnetdb database with another one?

Tags: asp.net, aspnetdb

I have an aspnetdb and I have created another aspnetdb for another website, but instead of starting from scratch, I would like to import all the data from the one that has users and other data into the new aspnetdb.  Is there a way to do this?  Are any tools available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would generate a script for the ASPNETDB tables (User Management Tables) and in advance properties select "Data Only" then follow Scott Gu's blog http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx  on how to create a fresh ASPNETDB tables in a new database. With the new database run your data only generated scripts to populate.

Comment: Xiasoft and Tamas. Did the above solution resolve your issue?

Comment: IMPORTANT: The 'Data only' script inserts `USE [aspnetdb]` at the beginning so be sure to change this to the correct DB name.

Comment: Note: I had no luck with SSMS Export wizard. Even selecting 'identity insert'  for each table didn't seem to be able to insert the rows in the right order to prevent constraint issues. This method worked for me.